# QGraphicsItem* conversion into long using reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, casting, qt5

I am creating test cases for my code. For that, I am capturing my code ( functions )  in `Capture Mode`  and in `Run mode` I am runnig that captured code. And if both are giving me same output, then my test case is pass otherwise it is fail.

`Capture code` (which is already written ) does not accept `non primitive` data types.
Means if some function has `Non primitive data types` as arguments, then it will not accept. So I need to write a capture function in such a way that it's argument will be primitive data types.

So the functions which has `non primitive` data types as arguments, I am converting them into `primitive data type` and then after capturing, again converting into it's original type using `reinterpret_cast`.
Let us say I have following function :

```
SelectObject()
{
  QGraphicsItem* currentSelectedItem = _scene->itemAt( some location );      
  long currentItem = reinterpret_cast<long>(currentSelectedItem);
  SelectObjectCapture(currentItem);
}

SelectObjectCapture(long currentSelectedItem)
{
    CAPTURE FUNCTION(SelectObjectCapture,currentSelectedItem);
    QGraphicsItem* currentItem = reinterpret_cast<QGraphicsItem*>(currentSelectedItem);   
    
    // then using currentItem in code
}
```

But this `currentItem` is leading to crash in `RUN MODE`. It perfectly works fine in `Capture mode` or without any mode.
Am I correct in `reinterpret_cast` ?

Comment: `long` might not be long enough to hold all of a pointer. Often long is 32 bits while pointers these days tend toward 64 bit. `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are a better choice.

Comment: I tried `long long` also. But still it leads to crash.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`'ing a pointer to an integer of *sufficient* size, and then `reinterpret_cast`'ing that integer back to a pointer, is guaranteed to give you back the original pointer. So, whatever problem you are having is not related to the casts themselves.

Comment: Besides the size issue, as @user4581301 specified, there might be a bigger issue: the pointer is already deleted when "Capture Mode" when you ends and you use "Run mode".